# What is the process for updating an active SilverLight MEF applications

Tags: silverlight, mef

Is there a recommended approach for updating actively used SilverLight MEF applications.  The update might involve a few related MEF components or something more signfiicant.  I want to avoid having the runtime attempt to load incompatible components (Component A updated loaded before update, but component B loaded after update).

Is there a mechanism built into .Net, SilverLight or MEF to support versions or should have parallel deployments with a launch page that redirects to the latest version of the application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are all your components in one XAP, or are you using the DeploymentCatalog to download multiple XAPs, or what?  If they are all in one XAP it will all be downloaded as a unit and you shouldn't have to worry about different versions of components being used at once.

If you are using multiple XAPs, then you probably either have a list of additional XAPs to download in your primary XAP, or you have a service that the application calls to figure out what components are available.  In either case you can have the list of XAPs be different between the versions of your app and point to the correct versions of your components.

Comment: Multiple components.  Some are rather large and may only be needed occasionally.  Sounds like we have to roll our own logic to validate/select modules to load.